# How to cast NSData to Data

Tags: swift3, nsdata, nsimage

I have created array of UInt8

```
var pixels: [UInt8] = []
```

filled by alpha, red, green and blue components and need to create NSImage from he array. I wrote following code

```
let imageData = NSData(bytes: pixels, length: 1000)
Swift.print(imageData)
newImage = NSImage(data: imageData as Data)!
```

where print command prints my bytes like ff0493f8 ff455772 ffa281ed ff9c14d7 ff6eb302... but creating of newImage fails with error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".
What I did wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Most probably, the cast to Data is not the problem. Are you sure that the data contains image data in a format that is accepted by NSImage? (JPEG, PNG, PDF ...)

Comment: [`NSImage(data:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsimage/1519941-init) does not accept raw pixel data ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues.

1. Why use `NSData` at all? Just use `Data`.
2. Your error is the fact that `imageData` doesn't actually represent a valid image so `NSImage` is `nil` but you try to force unwrap it.

Try something like this:

```
let imageData = Data(bytes: pixels)
Swift.print(imageData)
if let newImage = NSImage(data: imageData) {
    // Do something with the image
} else {
    // oops - can't create the image
}
```

Comment: let imageData = Data(bytes: pixels) and print commandes writes number of bytes bt image creation by newImage = NSImage(data: imageData)! end with the same "nil" error. So I assume my pixels array doesn't contain valid aRGB bytes. Any hint for this? Thanks.

Comment: `NSImage` expects the data to be in a supported format (PNG, JPEG, etc.). Raw RGB values is not one of them.

Comment: Ok. Any hint how to deal with RGB then? Thnx

Comment: I don't really know but have a look at the `NSBitmapImageRep` class.